# Make a DIV the default scroll on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a `div` within a `div` that's actually the main content of the page (due to the way the client wanted it to slide into the page with a parallax effect). The `body` has `overflow: hidden`, and the `div` with the content has `overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;` (so the vertical scroll works).

Unfortunately if the user loads the page and immediately presses PGNDN or scrolls the mouse, it attempts to scroll the `body` tag.

If the user clicks anywhere in the content in the `div` and then presses PGNDN or scrolls the mouse, then the right content is scrolled.

How can I mimic the user clicking in this `div` on pageload so that even if they don't click on the content all scrolling events will scroll the page content and not the `body`.

I've tried adding `tabindex=0` to the `div`. I've also tried adding an ID and forcing focus using JS. Neither

```
document.getElementById('focus').scrollIntoView();
```

nor

```
window.location.hash = '#focus';
```

worked for me.

jQuery is available.

Here's an example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rwqee8kb/)

Comment: You should be able to set `overflow:hidden;` on all parents that you don't want to scroll.  no?

Comment: Have you tried document.getElementById('Id').click()  on page load?

Comment: @ntgCleaner That would only prevent scroll, and not make scroll behaviour focus on that div by default, and I've already done it... the problem is that there's a top margin set, so the page will scroll the distance of the margin -- even though there's no scroll bar.

Comment: Could you post a minimum code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @Screech129 I just did and no luck.

Comment: @LGSon I'll try. It may be very difficult given the amount of effects happening on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt that seems to work well.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/2yfy7or7/1/)  (fiddle doesn't work in firefox but a html page does)

HTML

```
<div id="content" tabindex="0">
```

CSS

```
#content {
  outline: none;   /* remove the focus outline */
}
```

Script onload

```
var cn = document.getElementById('content');
cn.contentEditable=true;                      /* appears only needed in fiddle demo */
cn.focus();
cn.contentEditable=false;                     /* appears only needed in fiddle demo */
```

---

*Update*

*After I created and loaded your demo as a html page (no fiddle), you actually don't need the `cn.contentEditable = true/false`*